# Why java String.replaceAll regex removes part of string which it shouldn't?

Tags: java, regex

I want to use regex to remove all characters that are not in range from input string. Here is my code:

```
System.out.print("Input: ");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.next();
scan.close();
String formattedInput = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
System.out.println(formattedInput);
```

Here how it works:

```
input: test,test test
testtest
```

Why it removed 3rd occurence of test? I wanted him to remove only "," and " " in that particular case.

Comment: Change `String input = scan.next();` to `String input = scan.nextLine();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you used a scanner and calling `scan.next` only picked up `test,test`.

A nice way to debug these kinds of things would be to do a `System.out.println(input)` just before your statement that calls `replaceAll`.